# Pandas dataframe.corr() stripping columns from input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm learning how to use the pandas library in python3 and I've run into an issue with dataframe.corr()

Here's an example of my dataset

```
Date,Gender,Age at Booking,Current Age
2015-12-23,M,21,22
2015-12-23,M,25,25
2015-12-23,M,37,37
2015-12-23,F,39,40
2015-12-23,M,24,24
```

And here is how I attempt to load it/transform it

```
crime_data = pd.read_csv(crime_data_s)
print(crime_data.head())
print(crime_data['Date'])
correlated_data = crime_data.corr()
print(correlated_data)
```

Printing crime data head shows the 4 columns with some associated data, accessing column 'Date' and printing its values works just as expected however when `crime_data.corr()` is called and I print the data it has stripped all other items except "age at booking" and "current age" therefore making it shape 2x2.

Calling the `dataframe.info()` method I can see that the date and gender columns are being labeled as objects rather than relevant data what can be done to fix this so that I can attempt to run a correlation on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['Gender']=data['Gender'].astype('category').cat.codes
data['Date']=data['Date'].astype('category').cat.codes
data.corr()
```

Output

```
       Date  Gender    Age        curage
Date   NaN   NaN       NaN        NaN
Gender NaN 1.000000 0.162804 -0.703474
Age    NaN -0.162804 1.000000 0.814425
curage NaN -0.703474 0.814425 1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `.corr()` works only with numeric data type columns. You need to replace values `M` and `F` with for instance :
`crime_data['Gender'] = crime_data['Gender'].replace('M',1).replace('F',0)`